# How can I get a k-v pair in this case?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, keyvaluepair

I'm using spark to deal with some data:
now I have:

```
val firstRdd = datas.map(data =>
  if (data.Type == 1) (data.id, data))
val secondRdd = datas.map(data =>
  if (data.Type == 2) (data.parentId, data))
```

and then I wish to join firstRdd with secondRdd but I find that they are not in k-v pairs, so I can't perform join here, how can I get a k-v pair with the same structure here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to filter those rows that you want in each RDD and then create the pair rdd

```
val firstRdd = datas.filter(_.Type == 1).map(data =>
  (data.id, data))
val secondRdd = datas.filter(_.Type == 2).flatMap(data =>
  data.parentId.map(parentId => (parentId, data)))
firstRdd.join(secondRdd)
```

Comment: Yes It works fine thx, but I still can not perform join here, it says:type mismatch expected:Rdd[Int,NotInferedW], actual:Rdd[(Option[int], data)]

Comment: are  id and parentId of the same type?

Comment: can you post the type of data?

Comment: I've added a change, that I think might solve your issue, but it would be easier if you share the type of data

Comment: yes ids are int and parentIds are some(int) and I wish the key type to be int rather than Option(int)